# Proving whether or not a limit is correct.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am new to calculus. In class, we are learning how to formally prove a limit is correct. Say

```
         f(x)=x+2
         Say someone claims the limit as x approaches 2 is 3.
```

We were asked to check (formally) whether this is correct or not. I started by asking what values of x would keep the absolute value of "f(x)-3" less than some number, epsilon. I got that for this to hold true, the absolute value of "x-1" has to be less than epsilon. Then I said, well lets suppose that the limit is 3. Now lets suppose epsilon is 0.1. For the limit to be correct, there must be some range around 2 such that all f(x) lie within 0.1 of 3. But from previous work, I know that this will only happen as long as x is between 0.9 and 1.1.

Since I have shown that there exists some epsilon for which there is no range around 2 which works, the limit can not be 3.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct. When presenting your arguments, make sure you follow the exact definition. For example, we want $|f(x)-3|$ instead of $f(x)-3$.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct way of thinking about limit.

Answer (score 1):

If limit of $f(x)$ is $3$ then we can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $3$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $2$.

For any small positive $\epsilon$, that $f(x)$ close to $3$ means $|x-1| < \epsilon$.

But then $1-\epsilon<|x-2|<1+ \epsilon$, and it means that the distance from $x$ to $2$ is around $1$.

Thus no way to see $x$ be close enough to $2$, it implies that this given limit is not correct.

To be concrete, we can choose $\epsilon = 10^{-n}$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$ to see that $x$ cannot be close to $2$.